# How to add Subscriber Analytics data from Marketing Cloud into custom fields in Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have Marketing Cloud connected to Sales cloud via Marketing Cloud Connect.

I am able to see the 'View Marketing Cloud Analytics' links in the 'Contact Actions' section that I have added to the contact record.

[image]

As a user (including one  who doesn't have a Marketing Cloud license), I am able to navigate to a contact record and click on that link and then I am taken to the 'Subscriber Analytics' page:

[image]

However, I want to add a custom Contact field 'Bounces' and then for the data to appear in there from the Subscriber Analytics page. I don't want to have to keep clicking on that 'View Marketing Cloud Analytics' link.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Having followed up with Salesforce Marketing Cloud Support on this question, the response is that this isn't possible yet. One will have to leverage the 'View Marketing Cloud Analytics' link as per the screenshot in the question.